# Set default value in DataGridView combo box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'm using `DataGridView` in windows form to allow the user to add n numbers of rows with values enter by the user. One of the column of `DataGridView` contains combo box, which is displaying its items by using database.

I'm using the following code in Load event to connect `DataGridViewComboBox` with database :

```
private void PurchaseMaster_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = itemBAL.GetTable();
    bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
    ItemName.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    ItemName.DisplayMember = "Name";
    ItemName.ValueMember = "ItemId";
    ItemName.DataPropertyName = "ItemId";
    ItemName.AutoComplete = true;
    ItemName.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    ItemName.DefaultCellStyle.DataSourceNullValue = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
}
```

But whenever I not select any value from `DataGridViewComboBox` and click on save button I find `null` value in the table corresponding to `DataGridViewComboBox` value.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.IsNewRow)
        continue;

    DataRow dtRow = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        dtRow[i] = row.Cells[i].Value == null ? DBNull.Value : row.Cell[i].Value;
    dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
}
```

Could anyone please tell me why I'm getting null value in database for `DataGridViewcombobox` defult value, despite of using `DataSourceNullValue` property?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your other post should be helpful:
[Combo box is not displaying default value in DataGridView in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774245/combo-box-is-not-displaying-default-value-in-datagridview-in-c)

See the comment at the end of the first answer.  Setting a null value only displays a default value but doesn't actually set it.