# DGV combobox displays, but does not choose, default value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm adding a `ComboBoxColumn` to my DataGridView and, with BindingSources, linking it to a separate related Department table.

A new row displays the first listed department (Accounts), but it doesn't select it by default, causing the error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DeptID', table
>   'StaffDB.dbo.Staff'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Following advice from an answer [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774245/combo-box-is-not-displaying-default-value-in-datagridview-in-c-sharp#answer-6775758), I'm using the following to set the defaults:

```
    comboCol.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = _bsDept(0)("Department")
    comboCol.DefaultCellStyle.DataSourceNullValue = _bsDept(0)("DeptID")
```

This appears to work on debugging, with the values 4 and "Accounts", but still yields the same error.

Here are all the relevant settings for the ComboBox:

```
    Dim comboCol = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    comboCol.DataSource = _bsDept
    comboCol.ValueMember = "DeptID"
    comboCol.DisplayMember = "Department"
    'staff table..
    comboCol.DataPropertyName = "DeptID"

    comboCol.HeaderText = "Department"
    comboCol.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"

    'the first Department "Accounts" appears to be selected, but it isn't
    comboCol.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = _bsDept(0)("Department")
    comboCol.DefaultCellStyle.DataSourceNullValue = _bsDept(0)("DeptID")

    dgvStaff.Columns.Add(comboCol)
```

Why are my default values being ignored?
(The ComboBox works if I choose a Department myself.)

Comment: I am not sure those `DefaultCellStyle` props do more than control how Nulls etc are displayed.  There is a `DefaultValuesNeeded` event which might be more appropriate

Comment: Thank you, that makes some sense ;). If you add it as an answer I can accept it, using this code `e.Row.Cells("Department").Value = _bsDept(0)("DeptID")` in the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure those DefaultCellStyle props do more than control how Nulls etc are displayed, given the name. There is a `DefaultValuesNeeded` event which might be a more appropriate place to set default values.  For instance (some code I have handy that does just that):

```
Private Sub dgv2_DefaultValuesNeeded(sender As Object, 
              e As DataGridViewRowEventArgs) Handles dgv2.DefaultValuesNeeded
    'defaults
    e.Row.Cells("Fish").Value = "Cod"
    e.Row.Cells("Bird").Value = "Raven"
    e.Row.Cells("itemDate").Value = DateTime.Now.Date
End Sub
```

In your case, you would supply a value from the Department source.

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you. The naming of the properties doesn't help, given that the exception specifies a null value, and the properties are for 'default nulls', but there you go ;)

Comment: I more typically add the new row to the datasource...this is more for when `AllowUserToAddRows` = true.